Convert raw string (having escape characters) to unicode/utf8 string
In Python 3, how to convert an ASCII raw-string (that includes escape characters) into a proper unicode string?
As an example:
a = "ä"                         # note the umlaut
b = bytearray( a, "utf8" )      # yields: bytearray(b'\xc3\xa4')
s = r'\xc3\xa4'                 # note it's a raw string

In the example you can see how my source string s derives from the unicode string a, informed by b.  The goal is to find a function, F, such that a == F(s).  Thanks for your help!
I tried every combination of encode and decode and codecs that I could think of.  Note, in particular, that the following yields False:
a == s.encode('latin-1').decode('unicode-escape')


You were so close!
s.encode('latin-1').decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')


I usually use raw-unicode-escape instead of latin-1 (in both places). Doc: Python3 - Codecs - Text Encodings
